# Replacing data of one table using another table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have two table as follows.

Table : city

```
city_id  city_name   state_id
  1       Cachar       1
  2       Darrang      1
  3       Nicobar      1
```

Table 2 : locality

```
pincode  Address       city
110020   loni          Nicobar
110021   debru         Cachar
110024   rogar         Cachar
110023   akura         Nicobar
```

in table city i have 1430 rows , containing different cities in India.
And in table locality each city contains near about 100 pincode .

What i want to do? : 
i want to replace each city(column) in table : locality with its corresponding city_id in table : city .

Question : How can i do this ? Is there any fast way to this ? I don't want to use any programming language i.e. php or java. Is there any procedure, looping in Mysql ?

Result should looks like this:

Table 2 : locality

```
pincode  Address       city
110020   loni            3
110021   debru           1
110024   rogar           1
110023   akura           3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
UPDATE locality JOIN city ON locality.City = city.city_name SET locality.City = city.city_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the steps below:

- Add a temporary column in location table of type integer.

  `ALTER TABLE locality ADD temp_column INT;`
- Run the following query to update the corresponding city id in
  location table.

  `UPDATE locality 
  INNER JOIN city ON city.city_name = locality.city 
  SET locality.temp_column = city.city_id;`
- Drop the column city in location table.

  `ALTER TABLE locality DROP COLUMN city;`
- Now rename the column of the temporary column to 'city'

  `ALTER TABLE locality CHANGE COLUMN temp_column city INT(11) NOT NULL;`